# How to generalize polygones in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, generalization

I am working with vectorized greyscale images converted into polygon layers by the QGIS vetorize tool. Currently I am using a rather long way to get rid of small polygones.

I convert the polygons into lines, run the Generalizer Tool (Plugin) with the Alghorithm "Remove small object" and a Threshold of 2.0 and convert the hole thing back into polygons.

Is there a way to do the same thing without converting the polygons into lines? I tried the v.generalize, but it does not seem to have the same Alghorithm for small object removal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the workflow I propose:

- After vectorization go to attribute table and add a field called `area` and calculate the area of each feature with `$area`
- After this, you can select features with an expression like `"area" < 20` for example to get all features which are too small
- delete those or go the other way by selecting only the desired features and go on the layer -> Save as.. and check the "save only selected features" option
- after those steps you could still run the "simplify geometries" tool

Comment: That solved the question. Thanks! Sometimes the solution is so simple, that you just do not see it.