# How to Merge polygons while zooming out using leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, d3

I have created a map using leaflet, with polygons. Each polygon has its proper color(style) based on the number of inhabitants.
please see the following example: [Map](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/example.html)

I want to merge polygons as I zoom out. for example: after every 2 zoom levels, I want to aggregate 2 adjacent polygons into one, where the inhabitant number of the new polygon is the addition of the volumes of the previous 2 aggregated polygons. I found that there is a method called turf.union that is able to merge polygons. But the issue that I have is in term of the algorithm that will be identifying adjacent polygons and returning them. How can I achieve that? is there any library that can help me achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see a solution to make it on the fly in Javascript. The key word is **generalization**. So I'd suggest to rather 1) create your generalized  layers using some GIS tools and (2) to display them in your Leaflet map depending on the zoom levels.

I don't have an automated solution for (1). Have a look at this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243254/how-to-generalize-polygones-in-qgis). If there is not a lot of data, you may do it manually in a desktop GIS software.

For (2), you can add/remove layers in a leaflet map using something like:

```
if (map.getZoom() > zoom1 && map.hasLayer(myLayerforZoom0)) 
{
    map.removeLayer(myLayerforZoom0);
    map.addLayer(myLayerforZoom1);
}
if (map.getZoom() < zoom1 && map.hasLayer(myLayerforZoom1))
{
    map.removeLayer(myLayerforZoom1);        
    map.addLayer(myLayerforZoom0);
}
```

Hope it helps.

J.